# How to find the library <openssl/des.c> and usit in C programs

Tags: c, openssl, des

I found a code in C used to break a DES encryption by means of a brute force attack (I will attach the link), but it is using a library that I can not find, I tried to search it on the webpage openssl and on their github repository, but I got lost.

[What I am trying to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119046/brute-forcing-des-with-a-weak-key)

Comment: That's a source file, not a library.  You would have to get the source code for OpenSSL and compile it.  The file `des.c` will not work without the supporting code it expects — there's a lot of that.  You might need a header; you'd have to look where the other OpenSSL headers are installed, and if that is `/opt/openssl/include/openssl/des.h` and you write `#include <openssl/des.h>`, then you'd need to compile with `-I/opt/openssl/include` as one of the command line options.

Comment: Thanks! I found the source file, followed the instructions and now everything works correctly!